# How to make Quartz.net execute only remaining repeat count of a job?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

Let's say we have a job and corresponding trigger configured as follows:

```
var jobKey = new JobKey(typeof(HelloJob).Name, typeof(HelloJob).Name);
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity(jobKey)
            .RequestRecovery()
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity(string.Format("{0}Trigger", typeof(HelloJob).Name), typeof(HelloJob).Name)
          .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(1, IntervalUnit.Second))
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
              .WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
              .WithRepeatCount(9))
          .Build();
```

using "quartz.jobStore.type = Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz".

Well I expect the job execute 10 times in normal situation and of course it does.
The problem is that I want the job to continue the remaining repeat count if any stop occurres during its life cycle.

For example I stop the program when the fifth execution of the job is done and the next time that I run the program I want to execute the job only five times more but it is executed 10 times.

How should I configure Scheduler, Job and Trigger in order to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may do this by storing remaining count between program execution:

- on program "Stop" save remaining count in external storage (file, db, etc..)
  The best way actualy is to do this after each job execution.
- on program "Start" read value from *storage* and use it in `.WithRepeatCount()` instead of constant.

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for a solution embedded in Quartz.net. I don't want to deal with saving and restoring numbers. Moreover, let's say a power blackout might happen and I cannot detect the program Stop. I have to save the number of execution per job after each cycle in my own DB and it is somehow annoying. anyway I upvoted your answer. Any better solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the database objects are created and configure jobstores.

Look this example. It can help you.

https://github.com/Leftyx/QuartzNetAdoJobStoreSQLite